# How to check if your connection is accepted using TcpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I am making a simple application which will send and recieve messages through LAN. I am currently testing my application on localhost.

I want to check whether the `TcpListener` on serverside has accepted my connection, ie has it made a call to `AcceptTcpClient`.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
sf::TcpSocket socket;
sf::Socket::Status status = socket.connect("192.168.1.1", 53000);
if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
{
    // error...
}
```